# jquery clone not showing up where I expected

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a form with input fields and the client can click a button located at the bottom of the field, "Add a System".  This function will clone a div with an id="template".  so far so good.

```
Existing Form
Existing Form
Existing Form
Cloned 3
Cloned 2
Cloned 1
Add a System Button
```

but what I need it to do is move the cloned template as teh very last item just above the Add a system button:

```
Existing Form
Existing Form
Existing Form
Cloned 1
Cloned 2
Cloned 3
Add a System Button
```

where Cloned 3 is the where the template will appear the 3rd time the button is clicked.  If the user adds 20 systems, the button and the field aren't even on teh screen at the same time.  I looked for an insertBefore but apparently that doesn't exists in JavaScript.

JS Code:

```
function AddNewSystem(){    
    alert('Adding new system');
    var CurrentLi = $('.template');
    CurrentLi.clone().insertAfter( $('#cloned') );
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Excalibur/Rm4uf/1/) to see what I'm talking about.  Click the "Add a System" button at and where the word template appears, change it to a 1 (or 2 or 3, etc) and repeat this at least 3 times.  By this point you should see how the template is inserting.

Is there a better way to clone than what I'm doing?

Comment: Thanks to James Montagne.  I've update the jsfiddle to reflect the corrected function.  http://jsfiddle.net/Excalibur/Rm4uf/2/

Comment: it's not a good praxis to clone ID. Rather clone class elements. I'm pretty sure you don't need 20 same-name ID in your DOM. It could easily run you into issues later.

Comment: The I'd was a typo. Thanks for catching that.  My fiddle was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I looked for an insertBefore but apparently that doesn't exists in
>   JavaScript.

You are using jquery which **does** have an `insertBefore`.

http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

```
function AddNewSystem(){    
    $('#template').clone().insertBefore('#cloned');
}
```

Comment: OMG.  Thanks.  :)  I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

you can append them directly to `#cloned`

```
function Repeat()
  {
    var CurrentLi = $('.template').eq(0);
    CurrentLi.clone().appendTo('#cloned');
  }
```

## *[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm4uf/3/)**

p.s. i changed #template to class. It could run you in problems one day - to have 2+ same-ID-elements

Comment: Interesting using appendTo. Is one method better than the other?